# Is there any equivalent to JavaScript's decodeURIComponent() in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app with Angular 7. Unfortunately, facing problem while users are using '**+**' sign in their password. In Angular post request '**+**' sign is replaced by **space**.

I've found some solutions in stackoverflow and used JavaScript's encodeURIComponent() to encode the passwords. It converts '+' sign to '%2B'.

But, can't find any decoder in my API to decode the '**%2B**' to '**+**' sign. It is noted that my server side is written with ASP.NET (C#). Or, is there any way to send the password with '**+**' sign without converting it '**%2B**'

```
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

***Sample Password***: `'abc+123'`
***Without*** `encodeURIComponent()`: `'abc 123'`
***With*** `encodeURIComponent()`: `'abc%2B123'`

Comment: Could you use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` ?

Comment: This should be one of the correct answer. @Dia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way at server side:

```
string encodedValue="abc%2B123";
string decodedvalue= Uri.UnescapeDataString(encodedValue);
Console.WriteLine(decodedvalue);
-- or
string encodedValue1=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("abc+123");
string decodedValue1 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedValue1);
Console.WriteLine(decodedValue1);
```

Thanks